# My device back button is not working properly it goes to first html but return back to second html

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova-3

I am making an app in android with the help of jquery mobile(html5,javascript),cordova 3.2  in which two html page is there from index.html i am calling home.html  with the help of document.location.href but the problem is that my device back button is not working properly
is not working properly when every I click my back button on the device it goes to index.html but return back to home.html
how to resolve these problem please help me out

index.html

```
    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="subBtn">Submit</a>
    </div>
```

one.js

```
    $("#subBtn").unbind("click").click(function() {
        submitButton();
    });

    function submitButton(){
        document.location.href = "home.html";
    }
```

home.html

```
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>welcome to home page</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: dont use `document.location.href`, use `$.mobile.changePage("home.html")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
window.location.href = "home.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use location.href = "yourpagename.html"